# Message received from Json response is appearing only when If condition is inside DIV

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm a little confused regarding the below :
If I put the @if condition inside the DIV , the Json message will show. The problem here is that the Div color (green) will always appear in the view.

```
<div class="alert alert-success" align="center" id="message">
  @if(Session::has('message'))                           
    <strong>{{Session::get('message')}}</strong>  
  @endif
</div>
```

While if I put the @if condition outside the DIV as below, the message will not show.

```
@if(Session::has('message'))                
  <div class="alert alert-success" align="center" id="message">
    <strong>{{Session::get('message')}}</strong>  
  </div>
@endif
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, also what is the correct method to do it ?

Comment: To make sure there are no chances for duplication, I changed the $message variable, as well as the id to different names. Still the same.

Comment: It;s strange, mostly problem like this will caused by typo or silly mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

**For this action:**

```
@if(Session::has('message'))                
  <div class="alert alert-success" align="center" id="message">
    <strong>{{Session::get('message')}}</strong>  
  </div>
@endif
```

Make sure you return data with session from the controller.

You can `dd(Session::has('message')` on your view file to check the session variable.
I hope that tips will help you to find a solution. thanks!